# OSX shell (Terminal) via Python

Tags: python, macos

How can I return the OSX shell prompt to a user via Python?

I would like to implement my own "remote terminal".
I am trying this one, but it executes just a single command per time. 
I would like it to be persistent like as in a terminal window.

```
import socket
import threading
import subprocess

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9997

# how to connect?
# telnet 0.0.0.0 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
server.listen(5)
print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)


# this is our client-handling thread
def handle_client(client_socket):
    try:
        while True:
            # print out what the client sends
            request = client_socket.recv(1024)
            print "[*] Received: %s" % request

            # send back a packet
            # client_socket.send("ACK!\n")

            if request == "quit": break
            # do shell command
            proc = subprocess.Popen(request.strip(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

            # read output
            stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

            # send output to attacker
            client_socket.send(stdout_value)

    except:
        print "Connection failed. Closing port..."
        client_socket.close()

while True:
    client,addr = server.accept()
    print "[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])
    # spin up our client thread to handle incoming data
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Comment: I tried it and it allowed me to type multiple commands.

Comment: The only problem I had is that `quit` didn't work. That's because `request` contains a newline at the end, and you're not stripping that off before comparing.

Comment: You're also not checking for EOF on the socket. So when I closed the connection, it went into a loop printing `Received:`